# How to keep num pad on while starting my Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have done the following changes in my registry of windows 8.1

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ Control Panel\Keyboard
```

set the value of `InitialKeyboardIndicator` is 2 but still the num pad is off while starting my laptop.

Answer (score 4):

Answer/Tip:
Check your BIOS Setup for an option to have "NumLock" on at boot.

*For registry hackers:*
Run regedit, do a backup, search for "InitialKeyboardIndicators" and set the REG_SZ value of all instances to "2"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw-isftXpXQ

Comment: Logically speaking though, shouldn't the OS option trump what you've selected in the BIOS?

Comment: Logic is one thing, OS and BIOS interaction another... ;-p - especially if the OS comes from MS.

Comment: Well MS' OS works fine here and so does its NumLock setting. Hopefully the OP will confirm whether your suggestion worked for him or not.

Comment: There is no option of NumLock on BIOS menu.

Comment: Then I can only recommend to use some other OS/Hardware. Fake (as in non-functional) and missing user preference settings are a no-no IMHO.